# Pass form to child component and validate the form in child component

Tags: angular

I have a submit button in parent component. Also I have several child components. Now I want to enable the button to save all values of the form in all child components once the validation passed.
 In parent component, I created the form group.

```
 public mainForm: FormGroup;
```

In constructor of the parent component,

```
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
       this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
       child1Form: this.fb.group({
           projectName: [null, Validators.required],
           projectSource: [null, Validators.required]
       });
      });
     }
```

In the parent html, we pass the form to the child.

```
<div>
  <app-child1 [child1Form]="mainForm.controls['child1Form']"></app-child1>
</div>
```

In child component html, the code is:

```
<form [formGroup]="child1Form">
   <div>
      <input [(ngModel)]="projectName" formControlName="projectName">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input [(ngModel)]="projectSource" formControlName="projectSource">
   </div>
</form>
```

In the ts file of the child component, we use the form from the parent component.

```
 @Input() child1Form: any;
```

What I want is in the `ngOnInit` of the parent component, check the form validation.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.mainForm.statusChanges.subscribe(data => {
      const f = this.mainForm.controls['child1Form'];
      if(f.valid || f.dirth)
        // do something such as enable/disable the submit button
   });
}
```

However my question is the code didn't reach `statusChanges` part even I changed the text in the input control of the child component. I assume that when I type something the form's value or status is changed so I can do the validation.

Comment: On your child component try `<input formControlName="projectName">` and `<input formControlName="projectSource">`

Comment: @HuiZhao, you needn't subscribe to status change to enabled a button, just in .html `<button [enabled]="this.mainForm.get('child1Form').valid">submit</button>. But take account Joao say: use **formControlName** in child

Comment: @Eliseo, I have several child forms, child1 is just an example for demo.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add `formControlName` in the demo, just updated it. I have it in my real code.

Comment: `[enabled]="this.mainForm.valid">submit</button>` for whole form

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's solve this problem step by step:

1. Create a `parent` & `child` component
2. Add the following HTML template in **parent.component.html**

```
<form>
  <app-child></app-child>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

3. Add the following HTML template in **child.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="child1Form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="projectName" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="projectSource" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

4. Create a formGroup for `child1Form` in **child.component.ts** (I've declared the 'child1Form' in the 'child.component.ts' **not in the 'parent.component.ts'**)

```
  child1Form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.child1Form = this.fb.group({
      projectName: ['', Validators.required],
      projectSource: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
```

5. Now, subscribe to `statusChanges` & emit the value in the **child.component.ts**

```
  @Output() isChild1FormValid: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.child1Form.statusChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if(value === 'VALID') {
        this.isChild1FormValid.emit(true);
      }
    });
  }
```

6. Listen for the emitted value in the **parent.component.html**

```
<form>
  <app-child (isChild1FormValid)="enableSubmitButton($event)"></app-child>
</form>
```

7. Hold the value in a property inside **parent.component.ts**

```
  isChild1FormValid: boolean;

  enableSubmitButton(isValid: boolean) {
    this.isChild1FormValid = isValid;
  }
```

8. Enable the submit button if the `isChild1FormValid` property is `true`  (**parent.component.html**)

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isChild1FormValid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

9. [Full working demo in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-answer-for-question-58089596?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Sakib, it's unnecesary "output" the isChild1FormValid. a formGroup is valid is all its formGroup and formControls are valid. You can check in the main.component. Really it is unnecesary too subscribe to statusChanged, each time you change an input, Angular know if the form is valid or not

Comment: If I have several child components, should I use a long condition such as `[disabled]="!isChild1FormValid ||!isChild2FormValid || !isChild3FormValid || .... "`

Comment: use `&&` instead of `| |`

Comment: I saw in your parent component there is a`form` tag(Step 6). But you don't have it in the StackBlitz.

Comment: Strange! I'm seeing a `form` tag. Here is the parent component code ```<form>
  <app-child (isChild1FormValid)="enableSubmitButton($event)"></app-child>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isChild1FormValid">Submit</button>
</form>```

Comment: Did you provide the right link of StackBlitz? Maybe you edited it. I only saw `<app-parent></app-parent>` in app.component.html.

Comment: view the `parent.component.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199953/discussion-between-hui-zhao-and-sakib).